# EOFException when sending ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, tcp, objectinputstream, eofexception

I'm trying to send a blank TCP packet to a server running on port 80 however it gives me an EOFException when the server responds.

> java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3099)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
>       at me.adamstephenson.test.main.main(main.java:106)

```
ArrayList<String> results = getIPs();

    for (String ip : results){
        System.out.println(ip);

        String pingip = ip;
        pingip = pingip.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
        System.out.println(pingip);

        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(pingip, 80);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  // error here

            String msg = "blank";
            oos.write(msg.getBytes());
            oos.flush();

            //read the server response message
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();

            System.out.println(message);

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (ConnectException | EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to: "+pingip);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Does the EOFException mean that the response was blank?

Comment: no, it means the other side closed the socket before writing anything. Likely the server threw an exception somewhere, perhaps trying to read the request. It is suspect that this code just writes the bytes for "blank" into the stream. How does the server know how much data to read?

Comment: Have you tried ois.readByte() instead of ois.readObject()?.Because readObject() method returns de-serialized object which is present in other side.But you are writing byte array.

Comment: Yep just tried readByte, same issue. Going to redo the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the server didn't even create an `ObjectOutputStream` before closng the socket. Probably you sent it something it didn't understand, and maybe the application protocol it uses doesn't involve Serialization at all.

Port 80 is reserved for HTTP after all.